# onBackPressed() of Parent Activity is not getting called from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

My activity "Parent" has 4 fragments (A,B,C and D).
and I have override `onBackPressed()` method in my "Parent" Activity.
Now i can go from A->B,B->C, C->D, D->A and all other possible combinations through clicking on bottom navigation items. But when i press back button at fragment B,C and D, `onBackPressed()` method is not getting called , but if i do the same back thing from fragment A, `onBackPressed()` is getting called.
Sequence of bottom navigation drawer items : A, B, C ,D. A is the first fragment which gets loaded in "Parent" Activity.
These are the methods of "Parent" Activity.

```java
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
}

    public boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you are not blocking any back event `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` in other fragment B,C,D

Comment: @KrishnaSharma i checked it! All the fragments are alike without blocking any back event

Comment: code looks fine, didn't find anything wrong. Would be great if you share entire activity class.

Comment: Can you please share the whole activity? Also tell us If you are using viewpager or not

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the code with this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(a);
}
```

Place it under your "MainMenu", the one that uses the instance of your fragments by click-case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Elletlar onBackPressed() is not getting called from fragment